# Divide a calculated value/difference by the prior value -> 'slope'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, division

I have a pandas DataFrame `df` (gradient is the new calculated column):

```
Time Value1 Value2  gradient    
1        20     40       NaN    
2        30    100       0.5    
3        36    150       0.2    
4        18    100      -0.5
```

Now, I want to calculate all differences between the row y and the prior row x, divided by the value in the prior row.

Example: in this case, in the new column `df['gradient']` should I get in row 3 for 'value1' : 0.20 --> ((36-30) / 30)

I have now:

```
df['gradient'] =  df['Value1'].diff() / df['Value1']
```

But I know the `/ df['Value1']` is not correct. What's the right syntax in this case for dividing by the value in the prior row?

Comment: To format the frame, select the rows and hit control-K (or push the button above the edit box with two braces `{}`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `shift()` the column that you divide by. This moves each value into the next row down. For example if you have your `df` as:

```
   Value1
0      20
1      30
2      36
3      18
```

Then the gradients can be calculated with the division:

```
>>> df.Value1.diff() / df.Value1.shift()
0    NaN
1    0.5
2    0.2
3   -0.5
```